# Adding two new command clicks to form by copying

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I added two facilities to a form. When I try to run it, it says no selection is made.

If I select "all", it runs. I can't run SMC or SCC, the two additions to the form, individually.

I created the two facility clicks by copying SGV and WHT and renaming.

I edited the coding to run SMC and SCC, that's why it works when I select all.

[image]

```vb
Private Sub OkayCommandButton_Click()
    ' Determine which facility is selected
    Dim oCtl As MSForms.Control
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each oCtl In Me.SelectFacFrame.Controls
        If TypeName(oCtl) = "OptionButton" And oCtl.Value = True Then
            facOption = oCtl.Caption
            Exit For
        End If
    Next oCtl
        
    Debug.Print Err.Number
    If Err.Number = 438 Then
        MsgBox "No facility selection made. Try again."
        Unload Me
        End
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you highlight one of the buttons and show us its properties in the [properties menu](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/visual-basic-editor/propertieswindow-window.png)?

Comment: I just added the properties picture to the original post. I edited the (Name) and it still does not work. Do you think somewhere in the macro states which 3 letters before Option Button is Valid?

Comment: the code you've included seems like it should process the new buttons correctly - what other functions use `facOption`

Comment: So I narrow the issue down to the actual form and this code?For Each oCtl In Me.SelectFacFrame.Controls
        If TypeName(oCtl) = "OptionButton" And oCtl.Value = True Then
            facOption = oCtl.Caption
            Exit For

Comment: The reason I think this is because I renamed SGV and WHT to SMC and SCC and it ran perfectly fine. If I rename SMC and SCC to SGV and WHT it does not work.

Comment: i added a screen shot to show what I did

Comment: I think we need to see the code in another one of the form’s modules. I generally don’t like doing this but if you upload the spreadsheet to dropbox I can take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

An Option Button control has both a Name property and a Caption property. When you copied and pasted an old Option Button, you probably updated the Caption property but not the Name property. Your selection logic is based on the Caption property, but your action logic might use the Name property. Check the Name property for the two buttons you copied.

Comment: I changed the name to match and it still does not recognize it. I even try to just edit ANH and change it to SMC and it still does not work. Do you think somewhere in my code it states which 3 letters before Option Button is valid?